# How to create 2 product node displays

Tags: display-suite

How can I create 2 displays of a products node one for Authenticated users and one for anonymous ?

I am trying to create a single products display for my site that will display the product image and all of its fields for a single product basically like most eccomerce stores do with the image on the left and all the details on the right

there needs to be two versions of the display one for anonymous users that will display product without the add to cart button and price fields and rather display Text stating "we do not supply directly to the Public"

and then another display for authenticated users that will display the price and add to cart button.

this was easy to do for the grid views of products on my site I just created 2 views with role based access but for the actual single products node I aparently cannot use views because it is a node.

I am thinking I need to use display suit but how can i create 2 displays and use role based access.

Comment: Please add some more information to the question - What have you already tried, based on your own research? Why have you dismissed those methods? What went wrong? Did you get any errors? What were they? etc. Without a lot more information my guess is this is going to be closed v. soon as overly broad

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Entity view modes](https://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) to create two displays for an entity.

> The Drupal 7 successor to Build modes which will allow administrators
>   to define custom view modes for entities.

I'd probably then use Panels to output the product displays (but that's because I'd already be using Panels). Most likely two variants of the `node_view` page that both check user role. If a logged in user is discovered, then use a variant that uses view mode X, if the user is anonymous then use view mode Y.